# boolean switch: behavior of "any"

Tags: r, radix, any

I have a dataframe on which a logical test is applied: is any of the columns TRUE?

```
x=data.frame(label=c('a','b','c'),outcome1=c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE),outcome2=c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE),outcome3=c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE))
x=transform(x,result=any(outcome1,outcome2,outcome3))

x
#   label outcome1 outcome2 outcome3 result
# 1     a     TRUE    FALSE     TRUE   TRUE
# 2     b    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE   TRUE
# 3     c    FALSE     TRUE    FALSE   TRUE
```

I don't understand why the result of row 2 is TRUE since not all the column terms are true.

```
any(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)
FALSE
```

What is the correct way to apply "any" in this case?

Comment: `any` is not `all`. Look up "any" and "all" in a dictionary if English is not your first language.

Comment: @Roland: indeed not my first language :-). But to put it in a different way: why is any(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE) FALSE. whereas it is TRUE in the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code calculates

```
any(c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE),c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE),c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE))
```

and recycles the result to fill the column.

Comment: I will check "recycling" in the dictionary.